# При десериализации данных из xml файла выпадает исключение, где указывается, что в файле ошибка

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста  в чем ошибка и как ее исправить...)
В приложении пока что две формы. Form2 - форма для регистрации.

```
 namespace WindowsFormsExam
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                tbName.Validating += name_Validating;
                tbSurename.Validating += surename_Validating;
                tbDayBirthday.Validating += birthday_Validating;
                cbSex.Validating += sex_Validating;
                cbCountry.Validating += country_Validating;
                tbCity.Validating += city_Validating;
                tbGrowth.Validating += growth_Validating;
                tbWeight.Validating += weight_Validating;
                cbHeirColor.Validating += hairColor_Validating;
                cbEyeColor.Validating += eyeColor_Validating;
                cbZodiacSign.Validating += zodiacSign_Validating;
            }
            private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Person p = new Person();
                p.name = tbName.Text;
                p.surename = tbSurename.Text;
                p.birthday = tbDayBirthday.Text;
                p.sex = cbSex.Text;
                p.country = cbCountry.Text;
                p.city = tbCity.Text;
                p.growth =Convert.ToInt32( tbGrowth.Text);
                p.weight = Convert.ToInt32(tbWeight.Text);
                p.hair_color = cbHeirColor.Text;
                p.eye_color = cbEyeColor.Text;
                p.zodiac_sign = cbZodiacSign.Text;

                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
                using(FileStream fs=new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(fs, p);
                }

                Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

В ней при нажатии на кнопку донные сохраняются в xml файл с помощью сериализации.
 На основной форме (Form1) данные должны отображаться в DataGridView по нажатии на кнопку "Показать"(десериализация), но выпадает исключение, в котором пишется что в файле ошибка...

```
namespace WindowsFormsExam
{
    public partial class Form_1 : Form
    {
        public Form_1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();

        }

        private void btPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 XmlSerializer deser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]));
            using(FileStream fs=new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                Person[] people = (Person[])deser.Deserialize(fs);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("Surename");
                dt.Columns.Add("Birthday");
                dt.Columns.Add("Sex");
                dt.Columns.Add("Country");
                dt.Columns.Add("City");
                dt.Columns.Add("Growth");
                dt.Columns.Add("Weight");
                dt.Columns.Add("Hair_color");
                dt.Columns.Add("Eye_color");
                dt.Columns.Add("Zodiac_sign");
                foreach (var i in people)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Name"] = i.name;
                    dr["Surename"] = i.surename;
                    dr["Birthday"] = i.birthday;
                    dr["Sex"] = i.sex;
                    dr["Country"] = i.country;
                    dr["City"] = i.city;
                    dr["Growth"] = i.growth;
                    dr["Weight"] = i.weight;
                    dr["Hair_color"] = i.hair_color;
                    dr["Eye_color"] = i.eye_color;
                    dr["Zodiac_sign"] = i.zodiac_sign;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>Панас</name>
  <surename>Коваль</surename>
  <birthday>2.02.2001</birthday>
  <sex>Мужской</sex>
  <country>Украина</country>
  <city>Винница</city>
  <growth>176</growth>
  <weight>79</weight>
  <hair_color>    Брюнет</hair_color>
  <eye_color>Карий</eye_color>
  <zodiac_sign>Водолей</zodiac_sign>
</Person>>>
</Person>
```

В тексте об ошибке пишет что: "Необработанное исключение в приложении. В документе XML (2, 2) присутствует ошибка."
И еще файл всегда содержит только один объект класса, больше не добавляются, сохраняется только последний...

Comment: 1) Уберите [лишний код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 2) приведите [текст ошибки и пример вашего XML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: BOM? encoding="utf-8"? И действительно ли Ваш XML содержит два закрывающих тега Person, да ещё и в некорректном формате? Или это ошибка форматирования вопроса?